# Remap URL from a parent directory to Codeigniter root

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter to make a RESTFull service. 
I have the following directory hierarchy on my server:

```
- www
    - backend
         - application
                - controllers
                - modles
         - system
```

When i call any of my services i use the following url

```
example.com/backend/index.php/controller/param
```

What i want to do now is to make an **admin panel** that is called when the
user call `example.com`. I want the admin panel to use the same Codeigniter that i used for the web service (use some of the models or use some controller function indirectly) but i don't know how to redirect the url form `example.com` to `example.com/backend/admin` assuming that i have an `admin` controller that will call the appropriate views.

`$base_url = 'http://example.com/backend/'`

i tried to change it to `example.com/` but and use routing to
remove the need to call `index.php` before controller names but i got `File not found (404 error)`.

Is there any way to achieve what i want without playing with the .htaccess file

Comment: Actually, editor here doesn't allow, but you have to put scheme http (or https) and trailing slash in base url.

Comment: You need to put http scheme and trailing slesh in base url. Sorry, writing from mobile.

Comment: I know about that, it was just a typo, but my problem is that the Codeigniter files are in a subdirectory of the root.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

If You will add this code to the .htaccess file it will remove index.php from the url with is showing before controller.

and another way make your url seo friendly the is rourtes file in codeingiter
application->config->routes.php
there you can create the routes

[Here is the detail description on routes](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Comment: I don't want to play with the `htaccess` file. And i know about `routing` but from what i know, routing works on the url segments after the `base_url` and sense the `base_url` are pointing to a sub-directory that wont work. I tried to change it to site root but it seems that it should point to the Codeignitor root directory, the one that contain codeigniter files. In my case it is `backend`